# JS creating Cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am creating cookies in JavaScript, I have followed w3schools.com link, when I run the example on w3school its making cookie,but when I copy the code and save it on an HTML file, its not making cookie on my local HTML file
I also tried this[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825683/how-do-i-create-and-read-a-value-from-cookie)

this is what I am doing from w3schools [Example](http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_cookie_username)

I have tried in Chrome and Firefox as well, its not making cookie when I open local HTML file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use cookies, then use HTTP. Local files don't have cookie storage in most browsers.